# How to create a 100% static site with Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Maybe I am expecting too much ... but after extensive searches I could not find a descisive answer to my question. So maybe someone here can give me a hint where to look.

I want to create a small blog. This blog shall be statically served. This is promised by various articles and videos for nuxt. So I wrote some code and can serve my content. Also the server side rendering, including the dynamic routes, and `nuxt generate` basically work.

My problem is that the assets, referenced from the content, are not included in the static files. They still are links to the headless cms (Cockpit in my case) that will not be accessible from the deployed site.

It is clear that somebody has to parse the generated content in order to convert the links to the static locations and also extract the content of those assets to the dist folder, but I assumed that this is handled by nuxt that apparently is capable of doing so in some circumstances.

So am I doing something wrong? Is there a library for this task or would I have to write my own solution?

If this is not possible with nuxt - maybe someone has a tip what to use instead? I am looking for a solution where the backend is only needed when generating the site and everything needed for the site is generated from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a linkResolver. I usually stick with Prismic, and they tell you to set a linkResolver.js that will take care of links you create on the CMS, converting them to be actually usable.
More here: https://prismic.io/docs/vuejs/beyond-the-api/link-resolving

Comment: If I understand it right this linkParser basically rewrites the links contained in the document - so far so good.
But this is
a) bound to prismic.io - I want to avoid an externally hosted backend for my data
b) it does not care about the content which would have to be extracted to the dist folder.

The problem is that Nuxt has to crawl the content of the generated content for links that point to the same site and then prepare everything so that that content then can be served statically ...